# add checkbox checked to hyperlink

Tags: html, servlets, checkbox, hyperlink, https

I only have an option to create 1 single link to bypass a page from a 3rd party collecting the fields within this page on the process.
So far, I was able to create the link and bypass the 3rd party page by collecting all information except one - it works but it is missing this 1 field.

In this 3rd party page, there is this checkbox input unchecked where the user has the option to check it or not. I need to add to my link this value but checked, here is the 3rd party checkbox code:

```
<input id="flexibleDates" name="flexibleDates" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
```

I ran out of options perhaps one of you know how and it could be a silly input, but I wasn't able to make it work.

My link is, as of now, somewhat similar to where "value" is pre-set on a prior screen - again this link works for now but I really need to add the value of the checkbox:
https://secure.theirsite.com/US/reso/book.htm?_eventId=changeDatesAndPrefs&citycode=CODE

The question is how do I add the "flexibleDates" checkbox field checked into my link?

Thanks

Comment: `&flexibleDates=true&_flexibleDates=on`

Comment: I tried this one before and nope....sorry

Comment: Then send the form and look at the URL

Comment: [XII. ACCESS AND INTERFERENCE](http://hhonors3.hilton.com/en/policy/site-usage-agreement/english.html)

You will not use any robot, spider, other automatic device, or manual process to monitor or copy the Site or the contents or information (including the Information) contained therein without our prior express written consent. ... You agree that you will not copy, reproduce, alter, modify, create derivative works, or publicly display any content ...from the Site without our prior express written consent or the appropriate third party.

Comment: We are a franchisee...therefore allowed to do so

Comment: After reading the entire API finally found 0 or 1 - solved. Thanks

Comment: Great. Feel free to delete this very localised question